# Problem with adding smiles on photos with convolutional autoencoder

Tags: pytorch, autoencoder

I have a dataset with images and another dataset as it's description:

[image: attrs]

There are a lot of pictures: people with and without sunglasses, smiles and other attributes. What I want to do is be able to add smiles to photos where people are not smiling.
I've started like this:

```
smile_ids = attrs['Smiling'].sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[100:125].index.values
smile_data = data[smile_ids]

no_smile_ids = attrs['Smiling'].sort_values(ascending=True).head(5).index.values
no_smile_data = data[no_smile_ids]

eyeglasses_ids = attrs['Eyeglasses'].sort_values(ascending=False).head(25).index.values
eyeglasses_data = data[eyeglasses_ids]

sunglasses_ids = attrs['Sunglasses'].sort_values(ascending=False).head(5).index.values
sunglasses_data = data[sunglasses_ids]
```

When I print them their are fine:

```
plot_gallery(smile_data, IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W, n_row=5, n_col=5, with_title=True, titles=smile_ids)
```

[image: faces output]

Plot gallery looks like this:

```
def plot_gallery(images, h, w, n_row=3, n_col=6, with_title=False, titles=[]):
plt.figure(figsize=(1.5 * n_col, 1.7 * n_row))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0, left=.01, right=.99, top=.90, hspace=.35)
for i in range(n_row * n_col):
    plt.subplot(n_row, n_col, i + 1)
    try:
        plt.imshow(images[i].reshape((h, w, 3)), cmap=plt.cm.gray, vmin=-1, vmax=1, interpolation='nearest')
        if with_title:
            plt.title(titles[i])
        plt.xticks(())
        plt.yticks(())
    except:
        pass
```

Then I do:

```
def to_latent(pic):
with torch.no_grad():
    inputs = torch.FloatTensor(pic.reshape(-1, 45*45*3))
    inputs = inputs.to('cpu')
    autoencoder.eval()
    output = autoencoder.encode(inputs)        
    return output

def from_latent(vec):
with torch.no_grad():
    inputs = vec.to('cpu')
    autoencoder.eval()
    output = autoencoder.decode(inputs)        
    return output
```

After that:

```
smile_latent = to_latent(smile_data).mean(axis=0)
no_smile_latent = to_latent(no_smile_data).mean(axis=0)
sunglasses_latent = to_latent(sunglasses_data).mean(axis=0)

smile_vec = smile_latent-no_smile_latent
sunglasses_vec = sunglasses_latent - smile_latent
```

And finally:

```
def add_smile(ids):
for id in ids:
    pic = data[id:id+1]
    latent_vec = to_latent(pic)
    latent_vec[0] += smile_vec
    pic_output = from_latent(latent_vec)
    pic_output = pic_output.view(-1,45,45,3).cpu()
    plot_gallery([pic,pic_output], IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W, n_row=1, n_col=2)
    
def add_sunglasses(ids):
for id in ids:
    pic = data[id:id+1]
    latent_vec = to_latent(pic)
    latent_vec[0] += sunglasses_vec
    pic_output = from_latent(latent_vec)
    pic_output = pic_output.view(-1,45,45,3).cpu()
    plot_gallery([pic,pic_output], IMAGE_H, IMAGE_W, n_row=1, n_col=2)
```

But when I execute this line I don't get any faces:

```
add_smile(no_smile_ids)
```

The output:

[image]

Could someone please explain where is my mistake or why it can happen? Thanks for any help.

Added: checking the shape of pic_output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess, but it seems you are broadcasting your images instead of permuting the axes. The former will have the undesired effect of mixing information across the batches/channels.

```
pic_output = pic_output.view(-1, 45, 45, 3).cpu()
```

should be replaced with

```
pic_output = pic_output.permute(0, 2, 3, 1).cpu()
```

*Assuming tensor `pic_output` is already shaped like `(-1, 3, 45, 45)`.*

Comment: If I do this, I get runtime error: RuntimeError: number of dims don't match in permute

Comment: Could you print out the shape of `pic_output` (just after calling `from_latent`)?

Comment: Sure. If I change the line - appears an error, so I've printed it after this line (didn't change it): pic_output = pic_output.view(-1,45,45,3).cpu() The output is: torch.Size([1, 45, 45, 3])

Comment: Could you print its shape before broadcasting (before calling `pic_output.view(-1,45,45,3).cpu()`)?

Comment: It looks like this: torch.Size([1, 6075]) (Sorry for answering so late)

Comment: Shouldn't the output of your decoder be an image instead: are you sure `pic_output = from_latent(latent_vec)` has a shape of `(1, 6075)`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure - I've added a screenshot in my question

Comment: By the way, I try to follow this tutorial : https://www.kaggle.com/averkij/variational-autoencoder-and-faces-generation But there is everything fine and I get this problem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide your own source code version. I think you're missing something, since you're using a convolutional neural net, your decoder's output **needs** to be a 2D map

Comment: Here it is - I'm working on Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kbTVtVKI6qzIEK_dPwyEuOxFNCtZt4cO?usp=sharing

Comment: I see you have implemented two `Autoencoder` classes. If you intend to use the CNN, it seems you need to specify `train()`'s `is_cnn` argument. By default it is set to `False`, hence the flattened result `(1, 6075)`. Calling `train` as `train(X_train, X_val, autoencoder, epochs=30, batch_size=64, is_cnn=True)`. Let me know if that works.